# Align vertically ggplot2 two or more plots and changing their heights (with a heat map plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling to plot two or more plots in just one page. One of the plot must be a heat map plot (as it is called in the cookbook ggplot2 book) and the x-axis of all plots have to be perfectly aligned. I after digging up (mostly here), I have ended up with the following script. They are vertically aligned, but I can not change their heights. It follows an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

dataheat=data.frame(day=rep(1:100,each=51),depth=rep(seq(0,-50,by=-1),100),z=runif(100*51))
data = data.frame(day=1:100,y=-15000*runif(200),sys=rep(c("hsoil","hleaf"),each=100))

pdf("rwu_r.pdf")

p1 =  ggplot(data,aes(x=day,y=y,linetype=sys)) + geom_line() + theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position=c(0.85,0.8),legend.background=element_blank(),legend.key=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_text(size=14)) +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,4,0,0.5),"lines"))+
  scale_linetype_discrete(name="",labels=c(hsoil="soil",hleaf="leaf")) +
  xlab("Day") + ylab("Pressure head, cm") + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(0,100)) 


 p2 = ggplot(dataheat, aes(x=day,y=depth,fill=z)) +       
        geom_raster() +   xlab("Days") + ylab("Depth, cm") +       
      scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(0,100)) +
        scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))# +
#        theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5),"lines"))

g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)
g1 <- gtable::gtable_add_cols(g1, widths=unit(5,"mm"))
g <- gtable:::rbind_gtable(g1, g2, "first")

grid.draw(g)

dev.off()
```

Now I want that the height of the top plot is 10% the total height, and the second one is 85% the total HEIGHT. If I change the "theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,4,0,0.5),"lines"))" of the first plot, it will also change the second one.

Also I also would like to  add a third plot aligned with the other ones and take control of its height.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: something like `g$heights[[3]] = unit(0.1, "null")` maybe?